# Button Click and its parent Layout Click Conflict

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have button inside Framelayout. My goal is to change view pager item on button click and on anywhere outside the button click, i want to show a menu at the bottom. Problem i am facing is when i add the onclick lister on parent framelayout, my buttons doesnt work. instead of the buttons, framelayout click takes action and shows my menu.

**Here is my onclick listener code:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.source1:
            // Change viewpager page
            if (((MainActivity) getActivity()).getViewPager() != null) {
                SourceCommunicator sc = new SourceCommunicator();
                sc.referenceUrl = news.getSources().get(0).getSiteUrl();
                EventBus.getDefault().post(sc);
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getViewPager().setCurrentItem(2);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.container:

            // Show menu at the bottom
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new Communicator());
            if (showContentWriter) {
                referenceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                writterView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                referenceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                writterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            showContentWriter = !showContentWriter;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**My layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.ShortFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/previewView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/previewImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/newsLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/relatedNewsView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/previewView"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.shongkhipto.shonkhipto.Utlis.BanglaTextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Three astronauts return to Earth after 168 days in space"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <com.shongkhipto.shonkhipto.Utlis.BanglaTextView
                    android:id="@+id/descriptionView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="After spending 168 days aboard the International Space Station, NASA astronaut Scott Tingle, Japan's Norishige Kanai and Russian cosmonaut Anton Shkaplerov landed in Kazakhstan on Sunday. While Tingle and Kanai conducted separate spacewalks, Shkaplerov did a record-setting 8-hour-long spacewalk. It was Tingle and Kanai's first mission, while Shkaplerov has logged 532 days on three flights."
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/referenceView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.shongkhipto.shonkhipto.Utlis.BanglaTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="আরো পড়ুন"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/source1"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"

                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_left_24" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/source2"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_left_24" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/source3"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_left_24" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/source4"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_left_24" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/writterView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                    <com.shongkhipto.shonkhipto.Utlis.EnglishTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Short by"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.shongkhipto.shonkhipto.Utlis.BanglaTextView
                        android:id="@+id/writerTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=" Shifa Naseer"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relatedNewsView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/relatedNewsImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/error" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/full_gradient_bg" />

                <com.shongkhipto.shonkhipto.Utlis.BanglaTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="World must stand up to US 'bullying': Iran Foreign Minister"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: i noticed on adding the onclick listener on parent container, it also creates problem with the viewpager scroll

Comment: Try to remove `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`on the parent

Comment: tried without them as well

Comment: How do you assign your listener, as I've tried your code and it works?

Comment: just set the onclick lister
container.setOnClickListener(this);